# Freeing tabs in Lotus notes 8.x into separate windows

Tags: tabs, lotus-notes

Instead of having multiple tabs within the one big Lotus notes window is there any way to "free' a tab into a separate window. (Like Outlook)
Its very annoying as my work necessitates using databases and mail a lot and i want to split tabs into movable windows.

Answer (score 6):

ummm....

1) for an individual tab, right click on the tab and choose 'open in new window'

2) if you want this to be your default behavior, go to 'file>preferences>windows and themes' and choose 'Open each document in its own window' under 'window management'

You don't say what version of the Notes client you are using. I do know that the first option has been available at least in version 6.5. The second option came later - I see it in the latest client (8.5.2), but I don't know when it was added.

Comment: This information is true. The setting you are referring to in #2 has been in 8.5 since release, and has existed through all of the releases.